# Multiple single results from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of elements which contain some ids. I need to connect to firestore and fetch only the records which have each specified id.

My array:

```
    var ids = { 101, 201, 303}
```

and my firestore documents:

```
{
  "users": {
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "otherData:" "otherData"   
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name1",
      "otherData:" "otherData"   
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "name1",
      "otherData:" "otherData"   
    },
    ...
    {
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "name1",
    "otherData:" "otherData"   
    }
     
  }

}
```

How can I do that efficiently using db.collection('coll1').where() statements?
I have tried to fetch the data using forEach like this:

```
ids.forEach(id => {
  let result = db.collection('coll1').where('id', '==', id).get();
  ...
});
```

But each time I try doing it this way, it does not work.

I am new to the firestore environment and not sure how to do such an operation. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firstore compound queries for this. Link to officials docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).


Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.


Similarly, use the array-contains-any operator to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An array-contains-any query returns documents where the given field is an array that contains one or more of the comparison values


**You need to change ids to array type**

```
var ids = [ 101, 201, 303 ]
```

#### Query

```
db.collection("coll1").where("id","in", ids).get();
```

Comment: Thanks, for help, that is exactly what I needed :)